# Is it a problem with SPI bit-banging or the mode

Tags: spi, esp8266, bit-bang

After hours of debugging the SPI send bit-banging function and probing, I have come to a point where I could no longer understand whats causing the Si4455-RFIC to always return response of 0x00, including for CTS command. However I have hypotheses for this problem cause, which are:

1. I believe it would be mainly due to the Si4455 not being able to process the commands and hence returning 0x00
2. It's not processing the commands because it's having trouble interpreting it, because there is something wrong with my SPI bit-banging function or the data I am sending.

According to the Si4455 datasheet [here](https://www.silabs.com/Support%20Documents/TechnicalDocs/Si4455.pdf), it states the following on page 23 regarding the SPI mode of Si4455:

[image]

And shows this SPI timing diagram on page 22:

[image]

From the above information, it is understood that the host MCU  must put the data on the SDI of Si4455 during the falling edge of clock, so that the Si4455 can read the data on the rising edge of the clock. And the same applies with the Si4455. Based on this, I wrote a function that sends the data (Commands bytes) to the slave device i.e. Si4455 using the simple bit banging method as shown below:

```
void Spi_Send (unsigned char Spi_Data)
{

  unsigned char index=8,m,maskval=0x80,k;   
  m = Spi_Data;
  while(index)
  { 
    SPI_CLK_LOW;
    k = (maskval & m); 
    while (k == 0X80)
    {
      SPI_SDO_HIGH;
      k = 1;
     }
     while (!k)
    {
      SPI_SDO_LOW;
      k = 1;
    }    
    m = m<<1;
    index--;
    SPI_CLK_HIGH;

      }
   SPI_CLK_LOW;
  }
```

The below scope image shows the command and CTS response transaction that does the following (Yellow Signal -> Data and Blue Signal -> Clock:

```
  1. Make NSEL Low
  2. Send 0x44 Command -- That takes 8 Clock Cycles
  3. Generate additional 8 Clock Cycle to read CTS Response
  4. Make NSEL High
```

[image]

Below is the scope image of how I am handling the chip select between each transactions to read the CTS response (Yellow -> CS and Blue -> Clock):

[image]

We have already built the first prototype and have got this chip to work with the TI CC3200, but for some reason I am having trouble getting it to talk with the ESP8266EX. I'd appreciate if folks can please review the signals in the scope I have attached and assist/advise me as to if there is anything I am missing or, is the way I am handling the signals wrong? If we cannot resolve this issue in this week, then we may be forced to evaluate some other module, which would be sad, since we have got this chip working on our first prototype with TI CC3200.

Update 1: Please see the hardware schematics of the ESP8266EX Launcher Board [Here - Jump to Page 42 to 46 for Schematics](http://akizukidenshi.com/download/ds/espressifsystems/0B-ESP8266__Hardware_User_Guide__EN_v1.1.pdf). Note that there is a **1uF capacitor** connected to GPIO 13 i.e MISO line after the reset key. I have removed this capacitor, since it will not allow for SPI communication.

Update 2: I have captured the timing variations comparison between TIcc3200 and esp8266ex signals as shown below, w.r.t Si4455 SPI timing diagram above.

[image]

Comment: I have various SPI'able components, some use different 'clock high, data high' modes, and some are programmable. Your scope traces look clean(ish) (undershoots?). Triple check the mode, and then check again. If you have anything with a programmable mode, check you are initialising correctly, rather than allowing the reset default to persist, as this *may* change between implementations of part, compiler, removing an 'unimportant' bit of code. All of my software 'intermittencies' have had rational causes, and most of those have been careless defaults, and unintended changes.

Comment: "the host MCU must put the data on the SDO of Si4455" - **NO!** The host must put its data on the **SDI** pin of the Si4455. SDO is Serial Data **Out**, SDI is Serial Data **In**.

Comment: The pics shown seem to be ok.  Do you have for the data from the Si4455 to the MCU?

Comment: @PsychedGuy - Some strange parts of your scope photos include: Different voltages for the clock & data signals shown on the top image; even more different voltages between chip select and clock signals in the bottom image; you chose different reference levels (the arrows on the left side of each trace), which partly hides that the clock signal has *significant* spikes (~0.8V) below its logic 0 level. If I had your hardware, I would be closely investigating the schematic and SPI signals to better understand why there are those (imho unexpected) differences. Can you supply your schematic here?

Comment: @SamGibson - I had cross checked the schematics but could not find anything else connected to these lines apart from a 1 uF capacitor to the MISO line which I had removed. However, I have updated my question with the link and page number to the hardware schematics. May be you could see something that I couldn't. Just so you know, that I am using HSPI - GPIO 15 (CS), GPIO 13(MISO), GPIO 14(CLK), GPIO 12 (MOSI)

Comment: @PsychedGuy - Thanks for the schematics link. If you are using that exact "ESP8266EX Launcher Board" with its 3.3V supply to the ESP8266, then imho the blue clock signal in your 2 traces is abnormal (\$V_{oh}\$ too low, \$V_{ol}\$ too high = perhaps excessive loading). Without having the hardware in my hands, I can't tell if that is due to something on the launcher board, or your init code of the ESP8266, or the connections to the Si4455 (since those connections are not shown in the linked schematic). You could try disconnecting the Si4455 and comparing the clock signal then, with your photos.

Comment: @SamGibson - Currently I am supplying power to ESP8266EX LB through USB. In the init code, there is nothing but initialization of the GPIO's and calling the spi send function within a while loop. Cleaned the entire code having just the spi relevant ones. Another thing, what do you mean by imho?, I am not familiar with that abbreviation.

Comment: @SamGibson - I am currently checking the spi signals without connecting the si4455 and found something interesting. I will update regarding it soon.

Comment: @PsychedGuy - "I will update regarding it soon" OK, good :-) I just noticed that you asked earlier SPI questions, when using the TI CC3200. Look at your scope traces in [this question](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/248773/) and compare the clock signals (yellow, in that old question) to those (blue) in your new question. Some differences are clear - old clock signals are normal with high \$V_{oh}\$, low \$V_{ol}\$, none of the negative spikes seen on the (blue) clock signal in this new question between the elevated \$V_{ol}\$ (i.e. logic 0 voltage) and 0V. Hope that comparison helps.

Comment: @SamGibson - yes, you are right and I am currently on it. Between how do I overcome those high Voh and low Vol problems?. And if this could cause trouble to the si4455 to interpret the data correctly, I wonder how, as far as the TTL logic levels are met?.

Comment: @PsychedGuy - "how do I overcome those high Voh and low Vol problems?" *Those* are not problems; it is your recent (ESP8266 config) with its *low* Voh and *high* Vol which are the problem. I can't tell you how to fix that, until the *cause* is found. Without the hardware in *my* hands, I can only use the information which *you* provide. I have made a suggestion (disconnecting the Si4455 and seeing if the signal integrity of the SCLK signal improves) and I'm waiting for your feedback. However my experience is that long debugging sessions don't work well on EE.SE, so you are running out of time.

Comment: @PsychedGuy - "if this could cause trouble to the si4455 to interpret the data correctly, I wonder how, as far as the TTL logic levels are met?" (a) Your scope resolution was too low for me to know, but I am not sure the correct logic levels (CMOS, not TTL) are met. In any case, there is an abnormality with that SCLK signal. (b) Based on your earlier comment that the Si4455 "always return response of 0x00" then invalid SCLK would seem one possible cause for that behaviour. I can't force you to troubleshoot this that way that I would do. It is your choice whether you investigate SCLK or not.

Comment: @SamGibson - I have completed the timing analysis of the signals generated by the TICC3200 and ESP8266EX w.r.t Si4455 SPI timing diagram. I will update the results in my questions by tomorrow just for your reference and opinions regarding the results. Probably this will be the last.

Comment: @SamGibson - I have put up the timing details between the cc3200 and esp8266ex. And the SCLK of esp8266 still has some jitters and offset when checked without the Si4455.

Comment: @PsychedGuy - [part 1 of 2] "I have put up the timing details" - I see no problems in that new info. "the SCLK of esp8266 still has some [...] offset [...] without the Si4455" - imho that is still a significant warning. There shouldn't be voltage differences between SCLK (GPIO14) and CS (GPIO15) signals, both driven by the ESP8266. They should have the same Voh and Vol, but they don't. Since the cause of the differences between those 2 signals is known not to be related to the (now disconnected) Si4455, then it must somehow be related to the dev board, the ESP8266 or how you are using it.

Comment: @PsychedGuy - [part 2 of 2] I don't want to guess at more possibilities, when I cannot test them myself and there is not enough space & time here to guide you step-by-step. I am suspicious about what else GPIO14 (SCLK) is driving on your dev board (look at your schematic, and you will see GPIO14 has other connections) but there are other possibilities too.